# How to interrupt bash pipeline on error?

Tags: bash, shell, error-handling, pipeline

In the following example `echo` statement gets executed regardless of exit code of previous command in pipeline:

```
asemenov@cpp-01-ubuntu:~$ 
asemenov@cpp-01-ubuntu:~$ false|echo 123
123
asemenov@cpp-01-ubuntu:~$ true|echo 123
123
asemenov@cpp-01-ubuntu:~$
```

I want `echo` command to execute only on **zero** exit code of previous command, that is I want to achieve this behavior:

```
asemenov@cpp-01-ubuntu:~$ false|echo 123
asemenov@cpp-01-ubuntu:~$
```

Is it possible in bash?

Here is a more practical example:

```
asemenov@cpp-01-ubuntu:~$ find SomeNotExistingDir|xargs ls -1
find: `SomeNotExistingDir': No such file or directory
..
..
files list from my current directory
..
..
asemenov@cpp-01-ubuntu:~$
```

There is no reason to execute `xargs ls -1` if `find` failed.

Comment: Are you interested in also redirecting the output from the first command into the second like the pipe `|` does?

Comment: @Kos: yes, the point is that when the first command fails there is no output for the second command and no reason to execute it - the result of this behavior becomes unexpected.

Comment: Then it isn't so simple. The pipe stages work concurrently, so by the time the first command finishes (with some exit code) it may already have generated some output and passed it to the second command. One way to do what you want is using temporary files as buffers instead of piping.

Comment: If there is NO output on stdout when exit code is non-zero, then this information itself can be used for piping the data. No need to check for exit code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The components of a pipeline are always run unconditionally and logically in parallel; you cannot make the second (or later) processes in the pipeline only if the first (or earlier) process completes successfully.

In the specific case you show with `find`, you have at least two options:

```
find SomeNotExistingDir ... -exec ls -1 {} +
```

Or you can use a very useful feature of GNU `xargs` (not present in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html)):

```
find SomeNotExistingDir ... | xargs -r ls -1
```

The `-r` option is equivalent to `--no-run-if-empty` option, which explains fairly precisely what it does.  If you're using GNU `find` and GNU `xargs`, you should use the extensions `-print0` and `-0`:

```
find SomeNotExistingDir ... -print0 | xargs -r -0 ls -1
```

This handles every character that can appear in a file name correctly.

Comment: Can I execute pipeline **sequentially** as `command1 && command2` does? Is there any technical reasons not to do it?

Comment: You can run commands sequentially with `command1 && command2` as long as `command2` is not processing the output from `command1` directly.  If you need `command2` to process the output but only if `command1` is successful overall, then `command1 > tmp && command2 < tmp; rm tmp` works (write the output to a temporary file, check it worked, read from temporary file, remove temporary file).  You'd use a better name than just `tmp` for the file (at minimum, `tmp.$$` so that concurrent executions don't interfere with each other, but using `mktemp` for preference).

Answer (score 1):

In terms of command flow, the easiest way to do what you want would be to use the logical OR operator, like this:

```
[pierrep@DEVELOPMENT8 ~]: false || echo 123
123
[pierrep@DEVELOPMENT8 ~]: true || echo 123
[pierrep@DEVELOPMENT8 ~]:
```

This works since the `||` operator is evaluated in a lazy fashion, meaning that the right statement is only evaluated when the left statement evaluated to false or 1.

**note**: commands which are run successfully return exit status 0 when successful. Something other than 0 when they are not. in your example with `find`:

```
[pierrep@DEVELOPMENT8 ~]: find somedir || echo 123
find: `somedir': No such file or directory
123
[pierrep@DEVELOPMENT8 ~]: find .profile || echo 123
.profile
```

Using `||` wont redirect any kind of output from the command on the left of the `||`. 
If you want to run some command only when one succeeds you should just do a basic exit code check and temporarily store the output of one command in a variable in your script in order to feed it to the next command, like so:

```
$result=( $(find SomeNotExistingDir) )
$exit_code=$?
if [ $exit_code -eq 0 ]; then
    for path in ${result[@]}; do
        #do some stuff with the find results here...
        echo $path;
    done
fi
```

What this does: When find is run, it puts its results into the `$result` array. `$?` holds the exit code of the last run command, so here it is the `find` command. If `find` found `SomeNotExisitingDir` then loop through its results (since it might have found multiple instances of it) and do stuff with those paths. Else do nothing.   Here `else` would be triggered when an error occurred in the execution of the `find` command or when the file/dir could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with pipes because pipe creation will not wait for completion, other wise how could `cat | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'` work?. Simulating pipes with test and temp files:

```
file1=$(mktemp)
file2=$(mktemp)
false > $file1 && (echo 123 > $file2) < $file1 && (prog3 > $file1) < $file2 && #.... 
rm $file1 $file2
```

Comment: Can I execute pipeline **sequentially** as `command1 && command2` does? Is there any technical reasons not to do it?

Comment: there is a reason, most of the time the processes in the pipeline does not even terminate as in the `cat` example, or when you are filtering out a long running script's output.

Answer (score 0):

> > the point is that when the first command fails there is no output for the second command and no reason to execute it - the result of this behavior becomes unexpected

If there is NO output on stdout when exit code is non-zero, then this information itself can be used for piping the data. No need to check for exit code. (Except for the optimization part off course.)

e.g. If you ignore optimization part, consider only the correctness part,

```
find SomeNotExistingDir|xargs ls -1
```

Can be changed to

```
find SomeNotExistingDir| while read x; do ls -1 "$x"; done
```

Except for while loop, the commands inside it will not be executed. The downfall of this approach is, some information (like line numbers) will be lost for commands like awk/sed/head etc. to be used in place of ls. Plus, ls will be executed N number of times, instead of 1, in case of xargs approach.

Comment: but `find` does print to stout when it doesn't find anything and with exit status non-zero.

Comment: No, the standard linux commands would _generally_ print on `stderr`, rather than `stdout`. `find` also follows the trend. & only stdout will get piped, not stderr.

Comment: Yes, you are right of course. Apologies, I must have been half asleep when I wrote that..

Answer (score 0):

For the particular example you give, it's sufficient to simply check if there is any data on the pipe.  The problem you experience is that `xargs` is getting no input, so it invokes `ls` with no arguments, and `ls` be default prints the contents of the current directory.  anishsane's solution is almost sufficient, but it is not quite the same since it will invoke `ls` for each line of output, which is not at all what `xargs` does.  However, you can do:

```
find /bad/path | xargs sh -c 'test $# = 0 || exec ls -1 "$@"'
```

Now, this pipe line will always succeed, and perhaps that is not desirable (this is the same behavior you get with just `find /bad/path | xargs ls -l`, though)  To ensure that the pipeline fails, you can do:

```
find /bad/path | xargs sh -c 'test $# = 0 && exit 1; exec ls -1 "$@"'
```

There are some concerns however.  `xargs` will quite happily invoke its command with many arguments (that is the point of it!), but some shells will handle a much smaller number of arguements than xargs, so it is quite possible that the shell will truncate the arguments.  However, that is possibly an academic concern.